# Add a column to BigQuery results that adds a description for an ID in a column from the results

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BQ to pull some data and I need to add a column to the results that includes a lookup.

```
    SELECT 
 timestamp_trunc(a.timestamp,day) date,
 a.custom_parameter1,
 a.custom_parameter2,
 a.score,
 a.type,
 b.ref
FROM
 `data-views_batch_20221021` a
 left outer join (select client_uuid,STRING_AGG(document_referrer, "," LIMIT 1) ref from `activities_batch_20221021` where app_id="12345" and document_referrer is not null group by client_uuid) b using (client_uuid)
WHERE
 a.app_id="12345"
```

How can I add a column that takes an array in a.type and looks up each value in the dict. I currently do this in Python and it looks up the values in a dict but I want to include it in the query.
The dict is:

{23:"Description1", 24:"Description2", 25:"Description3"}

I don't have these values in a table within BQ, can I include it within the query? There are about 14 total descriptions to map.

My end result would look like this:

date | custom_parameter1 | customer_paramter2 | score | types | ref | type_descriptions

Edited to add that types is an array.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have these values in a table within BQ, can I include it within the query?

Yes, you can have them as CTE as in below example

```
with dict as (
  select 23 type, "description1" type_description union all
  select 24, "description2" union all
  select 25, "description3" 
)
select 
  timestamp_trunc(a.timestamp,day) date,
  a.custom_parameter1,
  a.custom_parameter2,
  a.score,
  a.type,
  b.ref,
  type_description
from `data-views_batch_20221021` a
left outer join (
  select client_uuid, string_agg(document_referrer, "," limit 1) ref 
  from `activities_batch_20221021` 
  where app_id="12345" and document_referrer is not null 
  group by client_uuid
) b using (client_uuid)
left join dict using (type)
where a.app_id="12345"
```

> There are about 14 total descriptions to map

You can add to dict CTE as many as you need

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to try it.

Can you elaborate on your different lines within the dict? Each one is different, are you providing options or are there requirements for each line? 

Thank you, total newb on SQL here

Comment: first line in dict has column names in it, the rest of lines can also have column names but they are optional, so I usually have them in first like only to at least save typing

Comment: Ok, now I'm going to throw another curveball at you, I will update my question because this is a very important detail I forgot... The types is an array and can have multiple entries. Will this change it?
I can run what you've provided but it doesn't add the column to the results

Comment: please do not change the question on which you already got the answer, as at least that will invalidate that answer! rather, if you forgot something or changed your requirements  - just post new one and we will be happy to further help! and meantime, confirm if the answer actually answers your original question!

Comment: I cannot confirm that it answered correctly because as I stated in a previous comment that when I tried it I did not get the additional column needed. When I tested this the results were the same, I didn't get anything additional within the results.

Comment: ... because you changed your question  - anyway - you the owner of your post, so hopefully someone will jump in and will be willing to risk their time here